# NextJS/ Firebase Next-auth TypeError: collection is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, next.js, typeerror, next-auth

This is a next.js web project and when I'm running it on a local server, it's showing a type error. I'm unable to understand what to do?

[image]

Can anyone kindly suggest me what to do?

```
///[...nextauth].js
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";
import { FirebaseAdapter } from "@next-auth/firebase-adapter";
import { db } from "../../../firebase";

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: FirebaseAdapter(db),
});


//firebase.js
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxxx.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "xxxx",
  storageBucket: "xxxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
  appId: "xxx",
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore();
const storage = getStorage();
export { app, db, storage };
```

Comment: What's in db? Doesn't next have some special node env treatment for public vars or something as well?

Comment: Docs show passing the Firestore instance, not the whole app. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next-auth/firebase-adapter

Comment: It isn't working as this hasn't been updated

Comment: "it isn't working"... Did you read the docs, specifically what to pass to FirebaseAdapter?

Comment: Note that the Firebase adapter is still experimental and may not work with NextAuth.js 4.